# Using KalmanFilter or KalmanEstimator

Tags: filtering

I have the following:

```
samplePoints = Range[0.0,6.0,1/60.0];
noiseFunction = Function@@{{t},Total[Sin[RandomReal[{ωs,188.0},12]t]],
   {Listable}};
signalFunction = Function[{t},(36(1-E^(-2 t))+
   (3*Sin[54*t]+4Sin[35.1*t]))Piecewise[{{E^-((0.5t-2)^2),t<4},{1,True}}],
 {Listable}];
inputSignal = signalFunction@samplePoints + noiseFunction@samplePoints
```

How would one use KalmanFilter or KalmanEstimator to do a good job of suppressing the high frequency noise in (inputSignal). I am not interested in forecasting ahead. I want to estimate the latest sample of signalFunction from the most recent  and previous points from (inputSignal).

EDIT
This figure is a close up of some of the samples.

[image]

The noisy points are in red and the single without noise is black. I am trying to simulate a situation where I have the noisy points, and get a good approximation of the black points (without noise).

Comment: The code, as provided, does not work! I get `RandomReal::unifr: The endpoints specified by {\[Omega]s,188.} for the endpoints of the uniform distribution range are not real valued.`. You should also include the definition of Omega and s.

Comment: I neglected to change \[Omega]s to a number or provide a value. \[Omega]s is a Symbol, not a product of symbols. That should be \[Omega\s=130.0  (i.e. endpoints {130.0,188.0} )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to apply the Kalman filter, you need to have a model for the process. For simplicity, try a (2,1) ARMA model. Next, it is necessary to remove the "trend" from the data. One way to do this is to use the moving mean. Hence:

```
trend = MeanFilter[inputSignal, 10];
deTrend = inputSignal - trend;
ma = EstimatedProcess[deTrend, ARMAProcess[2, 1]];
maFilter = KalmanFilter[ma, deTrend];
```

Here is the original inputSignal in blue and the de-noisified version in red:

```
ListPlot[{inputSignal,maFilter + trend}]
```

[image]

After playing around with the modeling assumption, it looks like we can get a smoother estimate using a more restrictive AR(1) model

```
trend = MeanFilter[inputSignal, 10];
deTrend = inputSignal - trend;
ma = EstimatedProcess[deTrend, ARProcess[1]];
maFilter = KalmanFilter[ma, deTrend];
ListPlot[{inputSignal, maFilter + trend}]
```

[image]

No doubt you could do better by de-trending using your knowledge of the signal function (rather than using the Mean).

Comment: Is using a mean filter considered the best way to get the trend if you don't know anything else? Is it standard to use this approach to difference out the noise? Finally, are there standard methods for choosing a model for the noise?

Comment: The reason for subtracting out the mean (and then adding it back in later) is that the noise model (assumed an ARMA process here) needs to be stationary. You usually would choose the noise model based on what you know (or believe) about the process... the better you can model it, the better you can do removing it.

Comment: @bill s: Thanks, but I wasn't able to find a variation of your code that does give something that resembles signalFunction@samplePoints. The first example under Applications at  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KalmanEstimator.html?q=KalmanEstimator   gives an example of doing this sort of thing. However, I don't know enough about the KalmanFilter to adapt that approach to my problem.

Comment: Hi Ted, I based this answer on the example in the Properties & Relations section of the KalmanFilter help file. This looks more relevant to your problem. The Kalman filter is a linear estimator, so it is not obvious what the best performance is because your noise is nonlinear. It seems to me that already with ARMA(2,1) the noise is reduced considerably.

Comment: @bill s.  I think you didn't understand what I am trying to do. I added a figure to clarify.